# addClass() to a Button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, addclass

I have a list with elements a user can choose from.
If you click an element you get a detailed view for that element. If the user wants, he can "favorite" this element, with the click on a button.

Now I have the problem, that I check on 'pageinit' of the detail view, if this element was favorited before (that info is stored in 'localStorage')
If it was favorited before, I want the button style to be changed.

My problem is, that when I change the style it changes it for all the "favorite"-Buttons, because they all have the same class.

So I thought I could solve that issue with applying a custom class for each favorite-button in each detailed-view. 
This is how I wanted to do that:

```
var className = selectedInstitut+''
$(".makeFavorit").addClass(className)
$(".makeFavorit ").find("." + className).text(selectedInstitut)
```

The first line is there, because "selectedInstitut" is a number.

But this code above does not work for me. If it works, it should change the text of the button to the "selectedInstitut", but it doesnt.
If I the name for the class manually, then it works. Any ideas?

(jQuery Mobile)

Comment: how is the click handler written

Comment: How do you know which button was favorited? what do you store in the localStorage

Comment: also share your html markup... you should not use the selector like `$(".makeFavorit")`, you will have to find the target element with relative position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I just found the solution:

```
var className = selectedInstitut+''
$(".makeFavorit").addClass(className)
$(".makeFavorit ").filter("." + className).text(selectedInstitut)
```

The difference is I'm using "filter()" now instead of "find()

Comment: Where you basically looking for `.hasClass()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
$(".makeFavorit ").find("." + className).text(selectedInstitut)
```

with this:

```
$(".makeFavorit ." + className).text(selectedInstitut)
```